# Find the poles of a function defined by series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence of distinct complex numbers such that $\sum_n \left| z_n \right|^{-3}$ converges, define

$$
f(z) = \sum_n \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2} - \frac{1}{z_n^2}
$$

Prove that the function is meromorphic and find it's poles.

---

So, my idea is to show that the function converges absolutely for any $z \not= z_n$, if we do the sum we get that the series is the same as

$$
f(z) = \sum_n \big( -z^2 \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2 z_n^2} + 2z \frac{1}{(z-z_n)^2 z_n} \big)
$$

I **think** that there exists constants c_1 and c_2 such that

$$
\left| \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2 z_n^2}  \right| \leq C_1 \frac{1}{\left|z_n \right|^4}
$$

and

$$
\left| \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2 z_n}  \right| \leq C_2 \frac{1}{\left|z_n \right|^3}
$$

for all $z$ outside of the sequence so it is dominated by a sum of absolutely convergent series.

To show it is analytic, if those constants are independent from $z$ then Weierstrass M-test can be applied and the convergence is uniform. Then we can use Morera's theorem to show that it is analytic.

The problem is to find those constants, if they exist.

Comment: The case of the [Weierstrass $\wp$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) may be useful for this question.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z) = \sum_n \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2} - \frac{1}{z_n^2}= \sum_n \frac{2z_n z-z^2}{z_n^2(z - z_n)^2}$$

For $U$ a disk of finite radius with no $z_n$ on the boundary then $$f(z)-\sum_{z_n\in U}( \frac{1}{(z - z_n)^2} - \frac{1}{z_n^2})=  \sum_{z_n\not \in U} \frac{2z_n z-z^2}{z_n^2(z - z_n)^2} \tag{1}$$
Since $|z_n|\to \infty$ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{z_n^3}{2 z}\frac{2z_n z-z^2}{z_n^2(z - z_n)^2} = 1$$ So $(1)$ converges uniformly on $U$ and it is analytic by Morera's theorem.

(alternatively it is mostly obvious that $(1)$ is holomorphic on $U$ since the series of termwise  derivatives converges uniformly too)

Comment: How does that limit being one implies that the convergence is uniform?